# File upload makes Node JS unresponsive with Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am using Multer Node JS package to upload files to my app sever , the code is basically typical upload file code

```js
const express = require('express')
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

const app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

But each time a file is being uploaded the Node server becomes unresponsive and frontend from other request doesnt receive any response from other APIs until the file is uploaded.

Whats the best way to tackle this ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unresponsive"? You have two routes, which one is become unresponsive? Did you end up your response by calling `res.json()`?

Comment: @MostafaFakhraee while the file is being uploaded the front end running on thr same node stops responding .

Comment: Thats probably becasue you are not ending the connection therefore same browser will stop using more and more (there is a limit of opened connection by browser and also a limit of connections that can be opened at one time for given page.

Comment: What is the size of file, if it is too big it might not be fitting in your memory and you should console the error in your multer function.Also print the request coming in multer function. This will help you in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, you must just send a response to the client by `res.json()` or `res.end()` :

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

const app = express();

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any

  res.status(204).end();
});

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any

  res.status(204).end();
});
```

Comment: thanks for revert but thats not the issue , we already do it when needed . Problem is for the moment when file is being uploaded it stops node from responding

Answer (score 0):

i can give you an example of how i implemented an imageupload in my app. it the code to upload a profile image for a user. i am also using multer middleware so it shoulder be similiar for you:

code is as follows:

```
// multer middleware:
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
  'image/png': 'png',
  'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
  'image/jpg': 'jpg',
};

module.exports = storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    let error = new Error('invalid mime type');
    if (isValid) {
      error = null;
    }
    cb(error, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const name = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
    const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    if (name.includes('.' + ext)) {
      cb(null, name)
    } else {
      cb(null, name + '.' + ext);
    }
  },
});
```

and here the code in the service handling the fileupload

```
// profile service in backend written in express
exports.uploadImage = (req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
  profileRepository
    .findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
    .then((response) => {
      const fetchedUser = response;
      fetchedUser.imagePath = url + '/images/' + req.file.filename;
      profileRepository
        .updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, fetchedUser)
        .then((response) => {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'profileimage updated',
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'uploading image failed',
          });
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'fetching user failed',
      });
    });
};
```

then i use the middleware in my profile routes file like this:

```
// profile.routes.js
const express = require('express');
const ProfileController = require('./profileController');
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/checkAuth');
const router = express.Router();
const fileStorage = require('../middleware/fileStorage');
const multer = require('multer');
// imageUpload
router.post('/user/image/:id', checkAuth, multer({storage: fileStorage}).single('image'), ProfileController.image);
```

my Controller then calls the service function with the actual business logic like this:

```
// profile.controller.js
const profileService = require('./profileService');
exports.image = (req, res, next) => {
  return profileService.uploadImage(req, res);
};
```

and finally my route is used by my app.js file like this:

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const profileRoutes = require('./profile/profileRoutes');

const app = express();

// set images path for saving images on server
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join('images')));

app.use('/api', profileRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

i hope i was able to point you in the right direction with my example

Comment: Are you using express with this ? If yes can you share that part too ?

Comment: i am using express yes. i have updated the answer to include all files and code for the backend, i left out the checkAuth middleware as its not relevant for the imageupload